# Android O Preview findViewById compile error

Tags: android, ambiguous, findviewbyid, android-8.0-oreo

I tried to test the Android O Developer Preview second phase.
After the project was created, I just clicked build and run but I didn't have any success.

Android default generated code below:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

compile error occurred.

```
Error:(18, 37) error: reference to findViewById is ambiguous
both method findViewById(int) in Activity and method 
<T>findViewById(int) in AppCompatActivity match
where T is a type-variable:
T extends View declared in method <T>findViewById(int)
```

Help me! How do I fix this error?

Edit #1

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

=> compile Error

Error:(18, 27) error: reference to findViewById is ambiguous
both method findViewById(int) in Activity and method findViewById(int) in AppCompatActivity match
where T is a type-variable:
T extends View declared in method findViewById(int)

This is not casting issue.

My build.gradle is here.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-O'
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0-rc2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 'O'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta1'
}
```

I tried to Android Oreo Developer Preview 2.
And use Android Studio 3.0 Canary edition.

Comment: Please post you code

Comment: Maybe worth a try: Can you set your minSdkVersion as well to 'O'

Comment: @Christopher Thanks, but same error. T.T

Comment: is this error is with toolbar only... or u get same error with textview or imageview or anything else?

Comment: @Kriti another widget also error. I guess it is android studio bug. T.T

Answer (score 2):

Your build.gradle looks good, but the compiler seems still to compile with supportLib 26 against older *compileSdkVersion* (25 or lower).

Try to sync gradle and *Build->Clean Project* .
If that doesn't help, *File->Invalidate Cache / Restart* should do the thing...

Answer (score 1):

The method signature of`findViewById` was changed with introduction of API-Level 25 to support generics and to remove the ugly casting:

The new method signature:

```
public <T extends View> T findViewById (int id);
```

compared to the old one:

```
public View findViewById(int id);
```

Therefore change your code to:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

Reference: [View|Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int))

Comment: This is not casting issue.

Comment: Hmm, ok. Can you show your build.gradle? I am interested in the support library versions you use and the platform version? Are they on the same level, e.g. 25.+?

Comment: Please see original article.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when my compileSdkVersion was 27 and buildToolsVersion was not 27.
Changed them to
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"
I think it happens when the buildToolsVersion is older than the compileSdkVersion.

Answer (score -1):

I believe they changed the method signature of findViewById so that you don't require the cast anymore. Try change that line of code to

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
```

Comment: I know how to work that infered type cast. This issue is not such case. AppCompatActivity has 'findViewById' method. and Activity has 'findViewById' method. compiler ambiguous this situation. first method '<T extends View> findViewById(int)', second method 'View findViewById(int)'. I tried to code 'Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) this.<Toolbar>findViewById(R.id.toolbar);'. But not success to compile.