# How to use public <T extends View> T findViewById (int id); in Activity Android compile sdk 26?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I notice that while using the new `compileSdkVersion 26` casting is no longer needed in Fragments (`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`). But I can't get the same method in `AppCompatActivity`

I have some preliminaries findings of the issue:

a. Inside a Fragment the new `findViewById()` method is always used and correspond to this:

```
public <T extends android.view.View> T findViewById(int id) { /* compiled code */ }
```

b. Initially I though this will mean that has something to do then with the Activity, but using `getActivity().findViewById()` does the same.

c. That leads me to think that the Activity inherits from another class, but when I trace upwards the `getActivity()` and `AppCompatActivity` I found both extends 'FragmentActivity'

d. While trying to use the `findViewById()` method in an Activity both methods are suggested, but finally casting is always needed despite selected the desired one.

e. I have found a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44127003/4017501). There is stated that the *new* `findViewById()` method belongs to `View` so I try to found a `View` inside a `View`, something like this `TextView tv = otherView.findViewById()` but still the casting is needed.

**So, how can I use the new `findViewById()` method in an Activity?**

Comment: "But I can't get the same method in AppCompatActivity" -- are you using `26.0.0` of `appcompat-v7`? [`AppCompatActivity` was updated to return `T` from `findViewById()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#findViewById(int)).

Comment: @CommonsWare your answer help me to figure it out! I was using `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'` and couldn't change it before because even when I try with the `0.0` versions then the sync would fail because the dependency was missing, that lead me to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45481709/4017501 so there is only to wait for people on Android Studio make it by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thanks, @CommonsWare because he's comment lead me to the solution.

I was using compile `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'` and couldn't change it before because even when I try with the `0.0` versions then the sync would fail because the dependency was missing, that lead me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45381506/4017501).

Again, as @CommonsWare point out the solution is to use the `AppCompatActivity` provided in the library `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'`. For doing it so you have to include Maven Google in your project dependencies `url "https://maven.google.com"`.

This is kind of a bummer because now there is only left to wait for people on Android Studio make it by default.

**gradle:project**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

**gradle:app**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is actually very simple and you can add it yourself to any class that needs it (or to a common base class):

```
protected <T extends View> T findViewById(@IdRes int id) {
    return (T) getRootView().findViewById(id);
}
```

You can even rename it to anything you want in order to resolve potential name collisions.

Have been using it [long before](https://www.techyourchance.com/casting-android-views/) Google finally added it to the framework.

Comment: This is a great work around, but I'm looking specifically to use the new method, thanks for your help