# Android Studio marks findviewbyid casts redundant but they aren't

Tags: android, android-studio-2.3

So I have this code:
[android studio marks casts as redundant.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI7gx.png)

But if I remove casts I will get compile error:

> Error:(42, 29) Type mismatch: cannot convert from View to Button
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain$ToolchainException: Jack compilation exception

What am I doing wrong?
Android Studio v2.3.3

Comment: Default way is to keep casts which was required until compileSdkVersion  26. If you set compileSdkVersion to 26 you don't need to use casting.

Comment: @FatihOzcan I have this issue with compileSdkVersion 26.

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project, it may help.

Comment: As pointed by others this is a problem because the sdk 26, please look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45577746/how-to-use-public-t-extends-view-t-findviewbyid-int-id-in-activity-android

Comment: @FatihOzcan this actually helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of View#findViewById on Android <= 25 is

```
View findViewById(int resId);
```

Requiring explicit cast for usage.

While the declaration on Android >= 26

```
<T> T findViewById(int resId);
```

It does the unsafe cast for you and returns the expected value for the assignment.

If you compile level is 26 you will be using the new method.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the elem with Id `buttonLoad` is not a Button but a View.

Provide the code of the layout if it isn't the solution

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was just cleaning up and rebuilding the project. Thanks to [Fatih Ozcan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5457853/fatih-ozcan)